# How to ignore dataset schema in WCF connection

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, wcf, serialization

On the server side of my application I have a function like this:

```
public function GetDS as MyTypedDS
    Dim dsRetVal as new MyTypedDS
    'Make fantastic things with the dataset
    return dsRetVal 
end function
```

On the client side I call this function through a generated "service reference":

```
Dim ds as Reference1.MyTypedDS = myRefInst.GetDS
```

**How can I disable schema serializaion of the typed dataset to reduce the traffic?**

Is it enough to set the SchemaSerializationMode of 'dsRetVal' to ExcludeSchema before returning it? Or is this option ignored by WCF?

Thank you

Comment: In all seriousness - you `DataSet` is a really horrible thing to send via WCF (virtually anything else is preferable). Regular typed objects would be vastly preferable. If the goal is to reduce bandwidth, there are alternative serializers available, but not really helpful for `DataSet`.

Comment: Added an answer suggesting `DataSet.RemotingFormat`, but just tested this with `DataContractSerializer`, and it is not used - so don't bother with that.

Comment: Old folks at my shop(Finance products shop) decided to write in house Data Storage just for that reasons DataSet over ".Net remoting" was a real snail. this Data Storage stuff still works like charm in WCF when i migrated all our .net remoting stuff to WCF

Comment: @Marc Gravell: Unfortunately it's impossible to change the data type in the near future.(Replacing the datasets)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried setting the RemotingFormat on the DataSet to SerializationFormat.Binary? We use this extensively in .Net Remoting of DataSets (which, of course we only use when absolutely necessary) and it helps significantly with the performance.

A couple of other options:

1) Binary serialize the DataSet and just transfer the ByteArray

2) Serialize the DataSet into a string format (i.e. JSON) then zip the resultant string and transfer the zipped data.